# Skipping entry in package table because it is not complex

Tags: android

In Logcat I get the following:

> W/ResourceType(12122): Skipping entry 0x7f02000c in package table 0 because it is not complex!

I checked R.java and 0x7f02000c is the following selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_play" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ab_solid_background" />
</selector>
```

Every time I bring up the activity, which uses this selector for the background of buttons, I get dozens of these warnings, which makes debugging a mess. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late for an answer but
I think, you should take a look at R file, see the int id with the item and check the associative attributes with these widgets